# How many bytes of content does the client expect to receive from the server?

Tags: packet, sniffer

How many bytes of content does the client expect to receive from the server?

[image]

I am confused. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Wireshark Follow HTTP]

You can use this feature:
Right click -> Follow -> HTTP Stream

Comment: How many bytes of content does the client expect to receive from the server? There is the word ' client expect'. Is this answer implemented to the above questions also?

Comment: What do you want to determine the number of bytes of? Of TCP packets or HTTP messages?

Comment: Http packet of clients only

Comment: So follow the instructions above to determine the exact number of bytes for each upstream or downstream measurement.